# How can I get oembed json for reddit comment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oembed, reddit

I'm trying to use `python-oembed` library to get oembed comment from reddit(https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/oEmbed):

```
import oembed

consumer = oembed.OEmbedConsumer()
endpoint = oembed.OEmbedEndpoint('https://www.reddit.com/oembed',['https://www.reddit.com/r/*'])

consumer.addEndpoint(endpoint)

response = consumer.embed('https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2safxv/we_should_start_keeping_giraffes_a_secret_from/cno7zic')
```

And get `oembed.OEmbedError: Missing required fields on OEmbed rich response.` error.

How can I retreive this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oembed returned by reddit is invalid.

From http://oembed.com/, §2.3.4.4, `width` and `height` are required for the `rich` type.

But, from [the reddit sample](https://www.reddit.com/oembed?url=https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/2safxv/we_should_start_keeping_giraffes_a_secret_from/cno7zic), we see that reddit doesn't supply a `width` nor `height` value.

You might need to get reddit to fix their broken oembed implementation, or you might want to use more forgiving library.